# Android: EditText hint in single line

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

For setting the Single Line in `EditText` we use `android:singleLine="true"` but I want to set the single line for the Hint Text, it is large and I want to show it in  a one line like:

> http://google.myopenid.stackoverflow.com

I am using the following code:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="@string/defaultUrl"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Note: `defaultUrl` is dynamic and very long URL.

Comment: so you wan tht hint url should be displayed at only as one line?

Comment: you are using this long Hint Text in one line and does it make any sense when user won't be able to read all at once?

Comment: I am trying to show only the small url and then append like google.com/...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use

`android:ellipsize="end"`

`android:maxLines="1"`

to show your hint text in single line but you wont be able to see the whole text because 
`android:ellipsize="end"` truncates the text at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: I try it already ,it is not working. thanks for you support.If have any other idea or can just tell me how to customize the class.

Answer (score -2):

Same issue.

Solution:

```
EditText.setHint("hint content".replace("\n"," "))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) 
 you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, 
 provide [answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)