# Freeze the text of the TextView + android

Tags: android, textview, trim

I am using textview for adding text in my application, i want the text should singleLine that i did, now the problem is that the word got cutted off

i.e suppose in my textview the text would Hello, how are you? What going on?
if the text is long and not coming the textView at end it would add ...
i.e Hello, how are you?..
not like his Hello, how are you?Wh..

the word should not be cutted off.

please help me in this,

thanks in advance...

Do reply as early as possible..

Comment: Try to make font size smaller if you want see all text in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this out,it is for the hint but have look may be helpful to you 
           [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871152/android-edittext-hint-in-single-line)

Comment: hey jack, thanks for your reply but i didnt want this actually i m looking for adding ... when the text is bigger but the word wont cutted off.

Answer (score 0):

If you have given `singleLine`, then it will show like that only...as Pasha said, you may reduce the font size or increase the edittext width for viewing it fully.

Comment: i dont want to view it fully and i want that if text is bigger that the width of textview given then automatically ... added but it wont cut off the words.