# android: singleline = true not working for edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to restrict the edittext entry to a single line but When I add the line `android:singleline = "true"`, the hint is disappears, and after entering 26 characters the cursor is coming down.

Here's my XML code:

```
   <EditText                      
            android:background="@drawable/edittxtborder"
            android:id="@+id/reglastname"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/reglname"
            android:textSize="12dp" 
   />
```

Comment: I want my edittext to take only single line

Comment: have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871152/android-edittext-hint-in-single-line

Answer (score 22, accepted):

add this code in your edittext xml code.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

this will work.

Comment: Thanks, but after entering the text if I press enter the cursor shd not come down to second line in same edittext. its happening here. Edittext shd take only single line

Comment: check again it won't create a new line.

Comment: Thanks again, after entering 26 charecters its coming down. can we restrict it?

Comment: where you are running this to device or emulator and which version

Comment: emulator and version is 2.2,  let me check in device

Comment: in device also same like after 26 characters cursor coming down in edittext box

Comment: what is your screen resolution mdpi or hdpi?

Comment: <EditText android:layout_marginLeft="128dp" android:gravity="center" android:maxLines="1"
      android:layout_marginTop="33dp" android:background="@drawable/edittxtborder"
    android:id="@+id/regfirstname" android:layout_width="163dp" 
    android:layout_height="31dp" android:hint="@string/regfname" android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textSize="12dp"></EditText>

Comment: use this code  <EditText android:layout_marginLeft="128dp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="33dp" android:background="@drawable/edittxtborder" android:id="@+id/regfirstname" android:layout_width="163dp" android:layout_height="31dp" android:hint="@string/regfname" android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true" android:textSize="12dp"></EditText>

Answer (score 3):

Use value for the attribute `inputType` other than `textMultiLine`. The input will be single line. The attribute `singleLine` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code and the problem is with android:gravity="center". Change it to android:gravity="left" and you will be able to see the hint.

Comment: Thanks , The Problem is not with hint actually I can do  something to show the hint but I dont want the cursor to come down to second line in the same edittext field , edittext shd take only single line not multiple

Comment: yes it is still taking single line not multiple line..... The cursor will be on single line....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setMaxLines(int)` to change line numbers programmaticaly.

```
EditText edit_field = new EditText(this);
edit_field.setMaxLines(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the button in the code directly by setting its input type to TYPE_CLASS_TEXT.  This will allow all kinds of characters, numbers, and space to be entered in, but no enter.  So in effect it will restrict it to one line.

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

You should also restrict the maximum amount of characters that can be entered into the EditText.  This can also be done through code using an InputFilter and calling setFilters method of the EditText with the InputFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

instead of

```
android:singleLine="true" due to deprecate
```