# restrict edittext to single line

Tags: android, android-edittext

possible duplicate : [android-singleline-true-not-working-for-edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909245/android-singleline-true-not-working-for-edittext)

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/searchbox"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder_full"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:hint="search...">
</EditText>
```

I want to make the above `EditText` to have only single line. Even if the user presses "enter" the cursor should not get down to the second line. Can anybody help me doing that?

Comment: use `android:singleLine=true`

Comment: replace android:lines="1" with `android:singleLine=true`.

Comment: true must be in quotes "true"

Comment: As singleLine became deprecated, you can use maxLines = 1 and inputType = text.

Comment: Using `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"` will solve the problem

Comment: android:singleLine="true" not android:singleLine=true

Answer (score 645, accepted):

Use `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:inputType="text"`

You forgot the [android:maxLines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines) attribute. And refer for [android:inputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) With your example, below will give this result:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/searchbox"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder_full"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:hint="search...">
</EditText>
```

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela in the current Eclipse IDE, no deprecation hint is shown, and android:maxLines does not restrict input to one line

Comment: @mjn, is it possible that you're compiling against an old SDK and thus not seeing the deprecation?

Comment: I'm using SwiftKey as input method and I'm having a problem with this. I manage in inserting `\n` characters with the keyboard, but they are displayed as spaces in the TextEdit. Any way to totally disable carriage returns?

Comment: @Praveen: Can you please give the reference where it says the [android:singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) is deprecated? I cannot see it there for API 23. I don't see it mentioned in the documentation and also I don't get any warning when I use it with `23.0.1` SDK

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Its not deprecated. Also, it was an edit. I didn't mention deprecated.

Comment: Does not make single line when writing text if you don't specify inputType. Otherwise it just makes single line for the hint

Comment: Worked for me :)
Anyway I was wondering why this piece of code didn't work for me?? 
android:maxLines="1"

Comment: Deprecated since API level 3. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine

Comment: This isn't working for me. If I set the edit text to have a text input type then the return key disappears in favor of a next button.

Comment: maxLines="1", not working for me, it still accepts multiple lines, it just restricts the height of the edittext.

Comment: If you use only android:maxLines="1" will not work.So you need to use both android:inputType="text" and maxlines -1.Then it will work perfectly

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen Then, which one is correct? Can you point it out please.

Comment: @Praveenkumar if you set `android:maxLines="1"` you see only one line but if you hit `enter` you still go on a new line and that's **not** what OP wants. The wanted behavior can be achieved with `android:inputType="text"`, as described by @ralphspoon below.

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen Even in my answer `android:inputType="text"` included.

Comment: right, now I see it, sorry, my bad! Maybe you want to point it out a bit more like you do for `android:maxLines="1"`

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen I have pointed it out clearly. Please refer the updated answer.

Answer (score 224):

Using `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated.

Just add your input type and set maxline to 1 and everything will work fine

```
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: If you don't specify inputType it won't work is what i found out.

Comment: your right. inputType="textMultiLine" will still give you multiline even if you set max line to 1.

Comment: Note that for `android:inputType="number"` there's already max 1 line.

Comment: This doesnt work if my textview is very long and I want it multiline, but not with newline characters.

Comment: @htafoya this code snippet works for making edit text single line. You can however, start a new question here at SO.

Answer (score 56):

`android:singleLine` is now deprecated. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine):

> **This constant was deprecated in API level 3.**
>
> This attribute is deprecated. Use `maxLines` instead to change the layout of a static text, and use the `textMultiLine` flag in the inputType attribute instead for editable text views (if both singleLine and inputType are supplied, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine).

So you could just set `android:inputType="textEmailSubject"` or any other value that matches the content of the field.

Comment: If you wanna a simple line text field, use `android:inputType="text"`.

Comment: Thank you @Mr. Bungle , textMultiLine worked for me !

Answer (score 18):

You must add this line in your EditText in xml:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: As other answers have noted - this has been deprecated in favour of `maxLines` and `inputType` combination

Answer (score 16):

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:inputType="text"
```

Add the above code to have a single line in EditText tag in your layout.

```
android:singleLine="true" is deprecated
```

> This constant was **deprecated** in **API level 3**.
>
> This attribute is deprecated. Use maxLines instead to change the
>   layout of a static text, and use the textMultiLine flag in the
>   inputType attribute instead for editable text views (if both
>   singleLine and inputType are supplied, the inputType flags will
>   override the value of singleLine).

Answer (score 13):

Now `android:singleLine` attribute is deprecated. Please add these attributes to your `EditText` for an `EditText` to be single line.

```
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 13):

This will work for the EditText:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Then I would set a max length for the input text:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Those are the 2 that are needed now.

Answer (score 11):

I have done this in the past with `android:singleLine="true"` and then adding a listener for the "enter" key:

```
((EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.mytext)).setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            //if the enter key was pressed, then hide the keyboard and do whatever needs doing.
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

            //do what you need on your enter key press here

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Include  `android:singleLine="true"`

Answer (score 7):

Everyone's showing the XML way, except one person showed calling EditText's setMaxLines method.  However, when I did that, it didn't work.  One thing that did work for me was setting the input type.

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

This allows A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and special characters, but does not allow enter to be pressed.  When you press enter, it'll go to the next GUI component, if applicable in your application.

You may also want to set the maximum number of characters that can be put into that EditText, or else it'll push whatever's to the right of it off the screen, or just start trailing off the screen itself.  You can do this like this:

```
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);
editText.setFilters(filters);
```

This sets the max characters to 8 in that EditText.  Hope all this helps you.

Answer (score 5):

You must add this line in your EditText

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

and another thing, don't forget set  `android:inputType` (whatever you want, text, phone .., but you must set it)

Answer (score 3):

use

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Programatically:

```
textView.setMaxLines(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to restrict you just need to set the single line option on "true".

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: singleLine is deprecated!

Comment: Works perfectly. With `android:maxLines="1"` user still can press Enter to break into multiline

Answer (score 2):

Also it's important to pay attention if the property android:inputType is **textMultiLine**. If so, the properties android:singleLine, android:imeOptions, android:ellipsize and android maxLines will be ignored and your EditText will accepted MultiLines anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Code instead of your code

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/searchbox"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder_full"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:hint="search..."/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Aleks G OnKeyListener() works really well, but I ran it from MainActivity and so had to modify it slightly:

```
EditText searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
searchBox.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            //if the enter key was pressed, then hide the keyboard and do whatever needs doing.
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBox.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

            //do what you need on your enter key press here

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

I hope this helps anyone trying to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your edittext

android:inputType="text"

Answer (score 1):

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

please try this code

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

Answer (score 0):

As  `android:singleLine="true"` is now [Depreciated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine) so use

## android:maxLines="1"

Use maxLines instead to change the layout of a static text, and use the textMultiLine flag in the inputType attribute instead for editable text views (if both singleLine and inputType are supplied, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine).

Answer (score 0):

in XML File add this properties in Edit Text

```
 android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

At XML file. Just add

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

for me i do it like this , go to your textView in xml file and add this two lines

```
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:inputType="text"`
```

Answer (score 0):

One more comment for all above. If you need the numerical input type just use `inputType="number"`. But if you will use `android:digits="0123456789"` you canot achieve the effect you need with any of attributes as `lines`, `maxLines`, `inputType`

Answer (score 0):

android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"

Answer (score 0):

**For compose**

```
TextField(
    //..
    maxLines = 1)
```

or

```
TextField(
    //..
    singleLine = true)
```