# Android EditText not Multi Line

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, multiline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [restrict edittext to single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978038/restrict-edittext-to-single-line)

I have 2 edit texts. My problem is, when I press the enter button in the keyboard, it creates another set of line. Or it creates like a next line in my edit text. I want to remove it and I want it to be in single line. Even if I enter the enter key in the keyboard, still it won't create a next line.

How do you do it?

Comment: `android:line="1"` or `android:singleLine="true"` in your EditText's attribute.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978038/restrict-edittext-to-single-line)

Comment: did you try yourEditText.setSingleLine(true); in the code or android:singleLine="true" in the xml ?

Comment: @ShaistaNaaz yes I did that already. Was answered by the person above and below. Sorry for this noob question. I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 31):

Try this in your EditText xml

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: singleLine is deprecated.

Comment: Use `android:maxLines="1"`. And use with `android:inputType="text"` and `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to prevent going to the next line.

Answer (score 9):

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittextView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Try this with your edit text in layout