# EditTextPreference single line

Tags: android, android-preferences, edittextpreference

Is there anyway to make an EditTextPreference single line? I think that there is no property by default, that can do that. Is necessary to rewrite the object? Anyone have this done?

Comment: Please note: Even if the input field is single line, you still need to check for newlines in the text, if they are not allowed in your data. The reason is, that a multi line text which was copied from elsewhere and then pasted into the single line edit field, will display as one line, but will still contain the newline character.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe `android:singleLine="true"` in the layout :

[restrict edittext to single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978038/restrict-edittext-to-single-line)

Comment: No idea why this answer and the one from CommonsWare was down-voted. This worked perfectly for me (2.3.3). See the Class Overview in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html).

Comment: Because it doesn't work in the latest version of Android.

Answer (score 6):

The following code works now with `androidx.preferences >= 1.1.0-alpha01`:

```java
        EditTextPreference author_name_pref = findPreference(getString(R.string.author_name_key));
        if (author_name_pref != null) {
            author_name_pref.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
                    editText.setSingleLine();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer for androidx. Kotlin style it looks less messy:

`preferenceScreen.findPreference<EditTextPreference>("the_key")?.setOnBindEditTextListener { it.setSingleLine() }`

Comment: It can be made shorter in java 8 too:  `EditTextPreference pref = findPreference("the_key"); if (pref != null) { pref.setOnBindEditTextListener(TextView::setSingleLine);}`

Comment: and put this code inside `onBindPreferences` override.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain `EditText` which backs up your `EditTextPreference` by calling `getEditText()`. And then do whatever you like with it, like with regular `EditText`:

```
EditTextPreference pref=new EditTextPreference(context);
EditText editText=pref.getEditText();
editText.setSingleLine(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

`<EditTextPreference>` supports the attributes available for `<EditText>`, and so you should be able to use `android:inputMode` and such to control the behavior of the `EditText` widget.