# Android - Questions about Edit Text in WebView

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-webview

I'm using a Edit Text to put in a URL to search in the Internet. But to use a URL, I need to put http:// in front of the Url. Is there a way, to hide this and use it for default?

And the other thing is to have only one single line in the Edit Text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way, to hide this and use it for default?

When you retrieve the value from the `EditText`, see if it begins with a recognized scheme (e.g., `https://`). If not, add it yourself, through string concatenation or `StringBuilder` or something.

> And the other thing is to have only one single line in the Edit Text?

[Use `android:maxLines="1"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10978159/115145) in the `<EditText>` element in your layout.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the first?

Comment: @ArvedVihweger: Only if you explain, **completely and precisely**, what you do not understand. Checking to see if a string begins with another string in Java is very simple, using [the `startsWith()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Yes, could you give me an example how to use the startsWith() method?

Comment: @ArvedVihweger: Given an `EditText` named `url`, `url.getText().toString().startsWith("https://")` will return `true` if the contents of the `EditText` begins with `https://`.

Comment: When I try to use this, it's the same like before. I have to enter http:// to load a URL in the WebView.

Comment: @ArvedVihweger: And, if you read my answer, you will see that I wrote "If not, add it yourself, through string concatenation or StringBuilder or something", where "it" is the scheme.