# multiple line edit text doesnot scroll when text exceed to many lines

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

i am creating a chat app like whatsapp 
on my chatting screen i have edittext where user can enter his message.
i want to expand its height to max 4 line  then if text exceed to 5th line the edittext have to scroll down showing new line. sometimes it work but sometimes edit text doesnot scroll down.

```
 <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiEditText
                android:id="@+id/enter_msg_txt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="9.2"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/type_message"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text" />
```

i had already search alot and check with these properties

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:editable="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
```

but still no luck. i think there is may be some rendering issue

Comment: try this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/38029494/3962677

Comment: @Kamlesh link you share is for single line. what i want is multiple edittext that expand and scroll

Answer (score 0):

This library may solve your problem.
https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AutoFitEditText.
Try it!

Comment: this lib does not increase edittext height it just resize the text of a fixed height edittext

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="int number" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (try it with your view )

- use **height** as `wrap content`,
- use  `lines` as lines count you want, so after scroll down is done

  ```
  <EditText
  android:id="@+id/reviewEditText"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:lines="3"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  />
  ```

and sure that `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
    <EditText
android:id="@+id/chatText"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:textSize="20sp"
 android:inputType="text" 
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:lines="1"
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
 android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Comment: your answer says max line 1 how it will work ???
i need multiple lines and vertical scrolling

Comment: u can set maxlines to as many lines you want, like for ex: maxlines="2" or "3"

Comment: use tag android:scrollbars = "vertical"