# How to create single line EditText in Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using Android 3.0. I need to create a EditText which should take only single line and text should scroll horizontally. I used Android:singleline=true. But when the text reaches end of the edittext width, the next text is coming  in next line.
Can anyone help me how to create single line EditText in android 3.0. The EditText that I used is enclosed in TableRow of TableLayout.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871152/android-edittext-hint-in-single-line

see the above link

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:scrollHorizontally

Use the `android:scrollHorizontally` attribute for XML or `setHorizontallyScrolling` for in code.