# Android: full text of EditText hint in a single line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I need my EditText hint to fit single line and at the same time to display the whole its text content. Any ways to do that? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871152/android-edittext-hint-in-single-line) is not very useful because it just cuts the end of the text.

Comment: Did you try this - `android:ellipsize="marquee"` [Try to see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) And, show me your `EditText` data in xml also

Comment: @SpK Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EditText cannot use the ellipsize mode TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE

Answer (score 0):

> Any ways to do that?

AFAIK, the hint is shown at the same text size as is whatever the user types. So, choose a smaller text size, perhaps based on screen size and density, that should be small enough to show everything.

Or, write a shorter hint.

Or, don't use a hint, but use a `TextView` label to document the `EditText`.